# Creating old neon advertisement

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, fonts

Good day everyone.

I am trying hard to create a high resolution computer made image of an old German "Plaste und Elaste" neon advertisement (see below).

After thinking a lot, the way to go I have chosen (although I am open to new ones) is creating a **three color, six line trail** (like a rainbow but with less colors) and molding it to the letters. 
When it has to be done to an L, it is a piece of cake, but with curves the job gets hard... so, my question is, **does anybody know how to do it with this method, or with a better one?**

Thanks in advance fellas!

[image]

Brief update: so far this is how it is looking

[image]

Final update: thanks to Cai, this is the result:

[image]

Comment: Why not look for a similar font then convert it to a vector shape so you can play with it afterward? Here's some examples: [Veselka](http://www.1001fonts.com/veselka-4f-font.html), [Monoton](http://www.1001fonts.com/monoton-font.html), [Picadilly](http://www.1001fonts.com/picadilly-font.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion, Paul :D. I thought about that, but none is a close enough match, and I want it to be as close as possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Create a custom brush in Illustrator.

1. Draw your lines
2. Drag the lines to the brushes panel.

[image]

3. Draw your "S" as a single path
4. Apply your brush

[image]

You can either create your brush as an *Art Brush* or a *Pattern Brush*. You can define custom corners and ends with a pattern brush which may be useful to you, or you can use an art brush which will stretch the entire of the brush over the path.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the method! I am going to try it ASAP, I will wirte back when I have it. :D (PD: I have always been reluctant to work with Illustrator, but you know, no pain no gain)

Comment: I finally did it, it wasn't easy (because I am no good with Illustrator) but I managed.